# How to set font/size for label widget in tizen native app

Tags: fonts, font-size, tizen, tizen-native-app

I have a tizen native app. I have used the following (after the typical `create_basic_gui` code):

```
/* peoConformant previously set for window object */
peoBox = elm_box_add(peoConformant);
object_content_set(peoConformant);
evas_object_show(peoBox);

peoLabel = elm_label_add(peoBox);
elm_object_text_set(peoLabel, "Label Text");
elm_box_pack_start(peoBox, peoLabel);

elm_object_show(peoBox);
```

Now I would like to change the font and the font size for the label. I know that I can add html code to the label text that would do this. But is there a way through native API calls? I have tried `evas_object_text_get(...)` and `evas_object_text_set(...)` but they don't appear to do anything.

Any and all help appreciated.

TIA

ken

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's best to use markup to change the font size.
There is no API to directly set the font size of elm_label.

```
elm_object_text_set(label, "<font=Sans><font_size=20>hello world</font_size></font>");
```

And to get/set the text of elm_label, use elm_object_text_get/set API.

```
const char* str = elm_object_text_get(label);
elm_object_text_set(label, "hello world");
```